# Java iteration for possible matches in ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

My question is about iteration and performance. Let's think of following case:

```
public class Car {

    private String name;
    private int type;
    private int horsePower;

    String getKey() {
        return type + "_" + horsePower;
    }

    private final int NUM_OF_CARS = 50000;

    public void test() {
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(NUM_OF_CARS);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CARS; i++) {
            Car c = new Car();

            if (i == 0 || i == 176 || i == 895 || i == 1500 || i == 4600) {
                c.name = "Audi A4 " + i;
                c.type = 1;
                c.horsePower = 200;
            } else {
                c.name = "Default";
                c.type = 2 + i;
                c.horsePower = 201;
            }

            cars.add(c);
        }

        // Matches should contain all Audi's since they have same type and horse
        // power

        long time = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();

        HashMap<String, List<Car>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();

        for (Car c : cars) {
            if (map.get(c.getKey()) != null) {
                map.get(c.getKey()).add(c);
            } else {
                List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
                list.add(c);
                map.put(c.getKey(), list);
            }
        }

        Iterator<Entry<String, List<Car>>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().getValue().size() == 1) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        Log.d("test", String.valueOf((SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() - time)));
    }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way of finding all Audi's here?

This took me **1700 ms**

Thanks.

Comment: Why are nested for loops a bad thing? Have you profiled and established that this part of the program is a bottleneck?

Comment: Should the collection be ArrayList or some other collection class/custom collection acceptable?

Comment: It could be something else than ArrayList, just need to hold all the Cars.

Comment: Tell more about your requirement. Do you know you want to find "Audi" type 1 and 200 horsePower? Then you don't need loop inside loop. Or do you want to find all sets of similar cars?

Comment: All Cars which have same type and horsePower, in the updated test code all matching Audi's have different name and the code works, but I don't know if it's the most fastest implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends *why* you're iterating. If you really do need to visit every bottom-level Car, then you don't really have a choice. However, if you're looking for specific matches to the String, then you might consider using a Map.

Comment: Matching criteria in the example is type and horse power, in happy case the name can be same with matching objects, but could be different, but still objects would pass the similar test

Comment: I updated my question, so you won't get the wrong idea, that I can use Map with car name key.

Comment: My response is still the correct answer. If you have to iterate over the entire List, then you don't really have a choice. If you're worried about lookup time and can do some indexing beforehand, then you should use a map. But premature optimization is the root of all evil, so you're probably worrying about something that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try (**Map**):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Basically it's a collection of **Hashmaps**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Here's an example:

```
  Map<String, List<Car>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();
```

Comment: Let's say that the name can be different with matching objects, like Audi A4, Audi A4 hatchback and so on, but they match because of same type and horse power.

Comment: I would more say that `HashMap` is a *type* of `Map`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a String you should use HashMap. Otherwise you cannot avoid that type of iterations as far as i have in mind.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot rely on name here, it could be BMW, Audi and Jaguar for example but they would match with type and horse power.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashing collections: HashSet that uses Object.hashCode() and Object.equals() to optimize search. How?

You must define your implementation of MyClass.hashCode() and equals(). hashCode() gives an integer representation of your object (you can do what you want here, but do it in a way where two different objects have different values)

HashSet will then do a modulo on your result ex: if the HashSet size is 5000 it will do a modulo 5000 and it will find the index where to put your object ex: if your hashCode() returns 10252, then 10252 % 5000 = 252. And your object will be put in an array with the index 252.

Finally, when you will ask (do I have an instance of "BMW x6", the object you ask for will have its hashCode() method called, which will return 10252 again. And HashSet will only search if it has an object in the 252 index.

If ever two objects give the same hashCode, then they will be compared through the equals() method.

I hope my explanations were clear. In short implement hashCode and equals() and try making the implementation of hashCode() optimized so you will gain time when filling your HashSet

You will probably also be interested in HashMap which stores keys and values where keys use the hashing mechanism: so you can find an object by its key

Comment: Did you say "HashSet"? If you use any "Set" it will throw out all duplicates! Collection will have only one object of one type and horsePower in this case. There is nothing to count after that!

Comment: Your object is responsible to furnish its own hashCode() method: so it's on you to decide whether you consider two cars with different options the same or not: you can include in your hashCode() method the fields that matter to you: if the difference relies in 

Car (model, power, color, version) just combine those values to compute your hashCode and equals methods

(RaviH do you understand how Sets work? your question is weird)